# error in running one of the SCIP's example

Tags: scip

I have a problem with running the VRP example in the SCIP package, I follow the instruction provided in this link: http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/START.php

but when I run "make" inside the created VRP directory, I got the following error:
No rule to make target `../../src/objscip/objscip.h', needed by`obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/main_vrp.o'.  Stop.

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you adjusted the SCIPDIR in the Makefile?

Probably, you just forgot to  run "make depend" before making, so that the old SCIPDIR is still stated in the dependency file.

Comment: I do not know how, but "make depend" is working now!! it did not work before, thank you!